# Spring boot: error while saving entity with oneToMany relation

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, flyway

I have two entities: `category` having `oneToMany` `products`.

Those are there classes:

Product.java

```
   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private Long NAME;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CATEGORY_ID", nullable = false)
    private Category category;

    //...getters, setters and toString
```

Category.java:

```
       @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private Long NAME;

        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category", orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<Product> products;

        //...getters, setters and toString
```

In the `CategoryBean` I have the same fields as the `Category` entity. In the `ProductBean` one, I have the same as the entity expect the `category` field (to avoid the infinite loop when mapping).

From the front (I'm using angular), I send the category object that has the same fileds as the entity. In other words, the category object that I send to the back in order to save it contains: a `name`, and an `array` of `products`.

To save the category, this is what I'm doing:

```
//from bean to entity
 Category category = CategoryMapper.toEntity(categoryBean);
 // NOTE: the category is containing the list of its products
 Category result = categoryRepository.save(category);
 return CategoryMapper.toBean(result);
```

But I got a `500 status` and this is the error:

```
00:04:08.940 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1747, SQLState: 42000
00:04:08.940 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

00:04:09.276 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN  ma.neoxia.exceptions.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler - INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR error 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:261)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at
```

Note that I'm using `oracle` and `flyway`. This is the PRODUCT `SQL` script:

```
CREATE TABLE "PRODUCT"
   (  "ID" NUMBER(10,0),
  "NAME" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  "CATEGORY_ID" NUMBER(10,0)
   );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PRODUCT_ID_IDX" ON "PRODUCT" ("ID");

ALTER TABLE "PRODUCT" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);

ALTER TABLE "PRODUCT" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("ID");

ALTER TABLE "PRODUCT" MODIFY ("CATEGORY_ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
```

And this is my Category `SQL` script:

```
   CREATE TABLE "CATEGORY"
      ( "ID" NUMBER(19,0),
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
      );

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "CAT_ID_IDX" ON "CATEGORY" ("ID");

  ALTER TABLE "CATEGORY" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);

  ALTER TABLE "CATEGORY" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("ID");
```

Comment: suppose the error is not realted to `oneTomany` relation. stack-trace complains about `invalid user.table.column`. Think the problem lies there. Please share user table and code that involves that operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your SQL files, you missed to add a foreign key constraint on `CATEGORY_ID` column, which must be identical in length with `ID` column in `CATEGORY` table

You can do it like this:

```
Alter TABLE PRODUCT
MODIFY "CATEGORY_ID" NUMBER(19,0);

ALTER TABLE PRODUCT
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CategoryProduct
FOREIGN KEY (CATEGORY_ID) REFERENCES CATEGORY(ID);
```

Comment: so the problem is with the sql script and not the java code?

Comment: @Llg I don't see a problem related to the shown exception in your shared Java code

Comment: I'm sorry but the migration failed: `SQL State  : 22019 Error Code : 911 Message    : ORA-00911: invalid character`

Comment: Even if when I have created the "Product" table I have mentioned that the "CATEGORY_ID" is NUMBER(10,0) ?

Comment: I test it but I'm getting the same problem

Comment: @Llg I don't have an Oracle installation on my machine, in general these are the main mistakes in your SQL files, try to debug the SQL code until you are able to change the column length and add the foreign key constrain